# Ruby FTP not working with IIS FTP server

Tags: ruby, iis, ftp

I have a ruby script that uploads a file via FTP.
I tested this with a LINUX server and the upload was working well.

But when I changed the upload destination to the production server which is a Windows Server 2012 R2 running IIS, I got the following error message:

```
A Connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect<2> <Errno::ETIMEDOUT>
```

I do however find the connection in the FTPlog:

```
2015-01-28 10:48:55 12.34.56.78 - 87.65.43.21 21 ControlChannelOpened - - 0 0 0 0 0
2015-01-28 10:48:55 12.34.56.78 - 87.65.43.21 21 USER .... 331 0 0 23 17 0
2015-01-28 10:48:55 12.34.56.78 WIN-0CFF8VSL25E\.... 87.65.43.21 21 PASS *** 230 0 0 21 15 94
2015-01-28 10:48:55 12.34.56.78 WIN-0CFF8VSL25E\.... 87.65.43.21 21 TYPE I 200 0 0 20 8 0
2015-01-28 10:48:55 12.34.56.78 WIN-0CFF8VSL25E\.... 87.65.43.21 21 PASV - 227 0 0 50 6 0
2015-01-28 10:49:16 - WIN-0CFF8VSL25E\.... 87.65.43.21 49994 DataChannelClosed - - 0 0 0 0 0
2015-01-28 10:49:16 12.34.56.78 WIN-0CFF8VSL25E\.... 87.65.43.21 21 ControlChannelClosed - - 0 0 141 46 21469
```

I am doing almost the same task with a batch script today, using windows native ftp cli, and this works fine.

Here is the ruby code:

```
require "net/ftp"
require "rubygems"
require "zip"

puts "Copying data"
FileUtils.cp("...", "...")

folder = "C:\\..."
input_filenames = ['...']

zipfile_name = "C:\\...\\....zip"
puts "Compressing data"
Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
  input_filenames.each do |filename|
    zipfile.add(filename, folder + '\\' + filename)
  end
end

progress = 0.0;
file_size = File.size(zipfile_name)

NET::FTP.debug_mode = true
puts "Uploading data:"
ftp = Net::FTP.new('12.34.56.78','xxx','xxx')
ftp.debug_mode = true
ftp.read_timeout = 10000
ftp.passive = true
ftp.putbinaryfile('C:\\...\\....zip', '....zip') do |data|
    progress = progress.to_f+data.length.to_f
    print "\rProgress: " + ((progress/file_size)*100).round(2).to_s + "%"
end
ftp.close()
puts "\nUpload completed!"
```

I am assuming there is no problem in the script, since it was working fine with a different server. What I am assuming it is, is a difference in how IIS' FTP server handles/responds to connections vs how vsftpd handles them.

Any suggestions to how to fix this?

Comment: This looks more like a firewall in the way which blocks the data connections.

Comment: @Steffen UllrichI don't see how that could be, because it works fine when using the windows ftp cli, from the same client and to the same host, and according to the logs it is able to connect, but then something happens.

Comment: Windows cli is using active mode by default as far as I know, but you are using passive mode. And what happens is that the data connections don't work, which is a typical problem in the interaction between NAT, firewalls, passive and active mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set passive to false and that solved my problem.